# Does List.find return a copy

Tags: javascript

I expected to update a user within `users` by doing find and setting the the returned value. However, `console.log(overview[userI]);` does not return print `null`.

```
var user = users.find(u => u.id===newUser.id);
var userI = users.findIndex(u => u.id===newUser.id);

user = null;

console.log(overview[userI]);
```

I then ran the following example:

```
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) {
    return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

let fruit = inventory.find(findCherries); // { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
fruit.quantity = 6;
console.log(inventory);
```

However, this time `inventory` is indeed updated as I expected with `cherries` now with a value of 6.

Why do I not see this behaviour in my first example?

Comment: In the first example you are reassigning the variable to `null` in the second one you are accessing the referenced object via the variable (and modifying it)

Comment: Probably because you are trying to do this in some asynchronous code. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning null to  a variable that previously had an object reference as value, does nothing to that object:

```
a = { test: 1 };
b = a;
b = null; // this does not influence the value of a.
```

In the above example, `b` first is made to share the value of `a`, but then goes its own way again. Neither of these two assignments changed the value of `a`.

But when you mutate an object, this will of course be noticed by all references to that same object:

```
a = { test: 1 };
b = a;
b.test = 2; 
console.log(a.test) // 2
```

So in your example, if you want your `users` array to get an element replaced by `null`, you need to *mutate* the array:

```
var userI = users.findIndex(u => u.id===newUser.id);
if (userI > -1) users[userI] = null;
```

Or, you could also re-assign the complete array with `map`:

```
var users = users.map(u => u.id===newUser.id ? null : u);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! How would you replace {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0} in inventory above with {name: 'rotten bananas', quantity: 10} where I use an arrow function to locate banana's after its name: (name) => name === "bananas"? I guess you could use map but wouldn't it nicer if there was an update method for list?

Comment: Just look how I assigned `null` in my answer and do it with `{ name: 'rotten bananas', quantity: 10 }` instead of `null`.